# scrolling the scrollview at the bottom programmatically - iphone

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I am dynamically adding some views in scrollview and increasing the contentsize of scrollview too but I want to scroll the scrollview ***at the bottom of its height***.

**scrollRectToVisible** is not helpful to me. It just scrolls to visible view of my iphone screen but I want to reach the bottom of contentsize of scrollview.

Can anyone give me some sample code?

Thanks,
Naveed Butt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like this instead:

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, [yourScrollView contentSize].height);
[yourScrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```

If you don't want it animated, just change `YES` to `NO`.

Answer (score 6):

I modified @jer's solution a little:

```
if([yourScrollView contentSize].height > yourScrollView.frame.size.height)
{
  CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, [yourScrollView contentSize].height - yourScrollView.frame.size.height);
  [yourScrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
}
```

This will scroll the content to the bottom of the UIScrollView, but only when it needs to be done (otherwise you get a weird up/down jumping effect)

Also I noticed if you don't minus the hight of the scrollview itself from the height of the content it scrolls the content up past where is visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGFloat yOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

CGFloat height = scrollView.frame.size.height;

CGFloat contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;

CGFloat distance = (contentHeight  - height) - yOffset;

if(distance < 0)
{
    return ;
}

CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;

offset.y += distance;

[scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

In case, if you want the Swift version:

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, max(scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height, 0) ), animated: true)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

This is more reliable

```
CGSize contentSize = scrollview.contentSize;
[scrollview scrollRectToVisible: CGRectMake(0.0,
                                            contentSize.height - 1.0,
                                            contentSize.width, 
                                            1.0)
                       animated: YES];
```